# Merge data from multiple columns into different columns by data name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following data structure in one table

```
Id      IdCrop1     NameCrop1   HaCrop1 IdCrop2 NameCrop2   HaCrop2 IdCrop3 NameCrop3   HaCrop3
20040   68          Tomato      65.00   54      Pepper      3.00    56      Cucumber    3.00
20041   54          Pepper      0.00    0       NULL        0.00    0       NULL        0.00
20042   54          Pepper      0.00    68      Tomato      0.00    0       NULL        0.00
20043   68          Tomato      30.00   54      Pepper      30.00   56      Cucumber    10.00
20044   68          Tomato      0.00    54      Pepper      0.00    0       NULL        0.00
```

And i want to merge the data from the different columns into 1 colum por each product/crop. So the result should be like this

```
Id      TomatoCrop1 HaCrop1 PepperCrop2 HaCrop2 NameCrop3   HaCrop3
20040   Tomato      65.00   Pepper      3.00    Cucumber    3.00
20041                       Pepper      0.00                0.00
20042   Tomato      0.00    Pepper      0.00                0.00
20043   Tomato      30.00   Pepper      30.00   Cucumber    10.00
20044   Tomato      0.00    Pepper      0.00                0.00
```

I think PIVOT could be a solution, but since i read in the doc, it needs an aggregate function, and i think all the possibilities would transform the output in a way that i dont want.

As last option im thinking in temporary tables by product and ID (like 60) and then merge manually...

Please help or suggestions are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Poor table design. You should have stored each article in a separate row.

Comment: Yeah, it's true, but i don't design it :(

Comment: I don't understand the second result. Why there is "tomato" in Corp 1 for id 20042 and in the first example not? And why there is "Pepper" in Corp 2 for Ids 20041 and 20042 and in the first result not?

Comment: @CPMunich Tomato is under Crop2 in the first example for ID 20442. The first example is poorly designed, Crop1 is not necessarily tomatoes, Crop2 is not always Peppers etc. J.Amaru is trying to order them so that Tomatoes are in the first column, Peppers the second, Cucumbers the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is close to what you want...

```
declare @tbl table (Id INT,IdCrop1 INT, NameCrop1 VARCHAR(100),HaCrop1 DECIMAL(4,2)
                          ,IdCrop2 INT, NameCrop2 VARCHAR(100),HaCrop2 DECIMAL(4,2)
                          ,IdCrop3 INT, NameCrop3 VARCHAR(100),HaCrop3 DECIMAL(4,2)
                   );
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES(20040,68,'Tomato',65.0,54,'Pepper',3,56,'Cucumber',3)
     ,(20041,54,'Pepper',0,0,NULL,0,0,NULL,0)
     ,(20042,54,'Pepper',0,68,'Tomato',3,0,NULL,0)
     ,(20043,68,'Tomato',0,54,'Pepper',0,56,'Cucumber',10)
     ,(20044,68,'Tomato',0,54,'Pepper',0,0,NULL,0);
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

WITH BetterTableDesign AS
(
    SELECT Id,1 AS Position,IdCrop1 AS IdCrop,NameCrop1 AS NameCrop,HaCrop1 AS HaCrop
    FROM @tbl
    UNION ALL SELECT Id,2,IdCrop2 AS IdCrop,NameCrop2 AS NameCrop,HaCrop2 AS HaCrop
    FROM @tbl   
    UNION ALL SELECT Id,3,IdCrop3 AS IdCrop,NameCrop3 AS NameCrop,HaCrop3 AS HaCrop
    FROM @tbl   
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT Id,NameCrop, asXML.col AS thisIsMyXMLColumn
    FROM BetterTableDesign
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT IdCrop AS [@IdCrop]
              ,NameCrop AS [@NameCrop]
              ,HaCrop AS [@HaCrop]
        FOR XML PATH('Crop')
    ) AS asXML(col)
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(thisIsMyXMLColumn) FOR NameCrop IN(Tomato,Pepper,Cucumber)
) AS p
```

With a SELECT like this you could get your desired output. But I would NEVER do this :-)

```
SELECT Id
  ,CAST(p.Tomato AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@IdCrop','int') AS TomatoID
  ,CAST(p.Tomato AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@NameCrop','varchar(100)') AS TomatoName
  ,CAST(p.Tomato AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@HaCrop','decimal(4,2)') AS TomatoHa
  ,CAST(p.Pepper AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@IdCrop','int') AS PepperID
  ,CAST(p.Pepper AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@NameCrop','varchar(100)') AS PepperName
  ,CAST(p.Pepper AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@HaCrop','decimal(4,2)') AS PepperHa
  ,CAST(p.Cucumber AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@IdCrop','int') AS CucumberID
  ,CAST(p.Cucumber AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@NameCrop','varchar(100)') AS CucumberName
  ,CAST(p.Cucumber AS XML).value('/Crop[1]/@HaCrop','decimal(4,2)') AS CucumberHa
```

Comment: @J.Amaru, is this helping you? If yes: Please vote up and7or mark as helpfull, thx!

Comment: Sorry i just tried right now, and it works! Thank you very much Shnugo!